# Silverlight Image Flip Animation

Tags: silverlight, animation

In my silverlight app, I have two images of equal dimension.

When the user clicks on the image I would like to animate the transition of one image to the other as if it were a piece of paper being flipped with the first image on the front and the other on the back.

I haven't worked with silverlight animation, yet so I don't know where to begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you will need two `Storybards` to begin with. Each `Storyboard` will be using [PlaneProjection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.planeprojection%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) (in this case I am using `RotationX` which rotates the images around the x-axis of rotation) to do the flipping animation.

In the following example, I have created `FlippingDown` and `FlippingUp` two `Storyboards`. I attached a `ControlStoryboardAction` behavior to each of them, they will be triggered when `MouseLeftButtonDown` is fired.

You'll need to reference `System.Windows.Interactivity` and `Microsoft.Expression.Interactions`.

```
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="FilppingAnimation.MainPage" Width="640" Height="480">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="FlippingDown">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationX)" Storyboard.TargetName="Front">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="90.0146"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="180"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationX)" Storyboard.TargetName="Back">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-180"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="-90"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="0"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="Front">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="Back">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Name="FlippingUp">
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="Front">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.6" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationX)" Storyboard.TargetName="Front" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationX)" Storyboard.TargetName="Back">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="-90.0146"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="-180"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="Back">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#FFCC9E9E">
        <Image x:Name="Back" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="/311438.jpg" Height="226" Width="129">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                    <ei:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource FlippingUp}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <Image.Projection>
                <PlaneProjection/>
            </Image.Projection>
        </Image>
        <Image x:Name="Front" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="/318549.jpg" Height="226" Width="129" d:IsHidden="True">
            <Image.Projection>
                <PlaneProjection/>
            </Image.Projection>
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                    <ei:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource FlippingDown}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Image>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could search for info on Projection animations in Blend. This looks like what you need: http://www.silverlightbuzz.com/2009/10/14/using-the-3d-tools-to-animate-in-blend/