# Changing image source in code

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

what i am trying to do is something like this on the mentioned event

```
    private void image1_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
            //this.animateIC1.Begin();
        Uri uri = new Uri("Images/1.png", UriKind.Relative);
        ImageSource imgSource = new BitmapImage(uri);
        this.imageBack1.Source = imgSource;
        this.Storyboard1.Begin();
    }
```

it has an animation which flips the front image and loads the backside image.

so i am not able to achieve the desired output as it shows no image after flipping.

this is my "secret" StoryBoard which is behaving perfectly in ExpressionBlend environment.

```
    <Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard1">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" Storyboard.TargetName="imageBack1">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="90"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="imageBack1">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" To="90" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" Storyboard.TargetName="image1" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
    </Storyboard>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void Change_Background1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Uri uri = new Uri("/img/day1.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
    ImageSource imgSource = new BitmapImage(uri);
    this.myImg.ImageSource = imgSource;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without you showing your secret Storyboard, I would guess that you simply set the image source before your storyboard is started.

I'm guessing that you will need to do [something along these lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423101/silverlight-image-flip-animation) and handle two image objects.